# C# Convert a Base64 -> byte[]

Tags: c#, base64

I have a  `Base64 byte[]` array which is transferred from a stream which i need to convert it to a normal `byte[]` how to do this ?

Comment: What is a "Base64 `byte[]`"? What encoding is it in?

Comment: can you put the code here?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you have a Base64 `byte[]`.  If it's in Base64 format, it's a string.

Comment: I think he meant that he has a byte array Base64 encoded.

Answer (score 239, accepted):

You have to use [Convert.FromBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) to turn a **Base64** encoded `string` into a `byte[]`.

Comment: i need `byte[] - > byte[]`  |  this method is `byte[] -> string`

Comment: Base64 is always ascii text. So just do `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(base64arr)` first.

Comment: There's a Convert.FromBase64CharArray now.

Answer (score 60):

This may be helpful

```
byte[] bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(stringInBase64);
```

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
byte[] incomingByteArray = receive...; // This is your Base64-encoded bute[]

byte[] decodedByteArray =Convert.FromBase64String (Encoding.ASCII.GetString (incomingByteArray)); 
// This work because all Base64-encoding is done with pure ASCII characters
```

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the `FromBase64Transform` class, used with the `CryptoStream` class.

If you have a string, you can also call `Convert.FromBase64String`.

Answer (score 3):

I've written an extension method for this purpose:

```
public static byte[] FromBase64Bytes(this byte[] base64Bytes)
{
    string base64String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64Bytes, 0, base64Bytes.Length);
    return Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
}
```

Call it like this:

```
byte[] base64Bytes = .......
byte[] regularBytes = base64Bytes.FromBase64Bytes();
```

I hope it helps someone.

Comment: UTF8 decoding is overkill though; it's always ascii text.