# How to send wav audio file using javascript and webapi c#

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

i need to send an audio wav file to the webapi controller for the microsoft bing speech api calls . 
what i have done is ,

1. Recorded audio converted to base64 data using javascript in the client side
2. invoked webapi controller using ajax call and sends the base64 audio data 
   as well.

   3.in webapi controller , converted the base64 data to bytes and sends to the restpi (microsoft).

please help me how i can do all these steps correctly

ajax call ,

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:49818/api/voice',
            type: 'POST',
            data: base64Data,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {

                alert(data);
            },
```

webapi controller method

```
string b64 = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            //string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\\base64.txt");
            var client = new HttpClient();
            byte[] toBytes1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(b64);
var uri = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/spid/v1.0/identificationProfiles/a1cb4a95-9e09-4f54-982b-09632aee7458/enroll?shortAudio=true";

            HttpResponseMessage response;
            byte[] toBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(b64);
            using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(toBytes))
            {

                content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                //content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("audio/wav");

                response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);


            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`contentType` is the type of data you're sending, so application/json; The default is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`.

If you use `application/json`, you have to use `JSON.stringify()` in order to send JSON object.

`JSON.stringify()` turns a javascript `object` to `json` text and stores it in a string.

```
data: JSON.stringify({"mydata":base64Data}),
```

In your controller you have to pass a parameter called `myData`.Something like this:

C#

```
public ActionResult MyMethod(string mydata){
   //code
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:49818/api/voice',
    type: 'POST',
    data:{"mydata":base64Data},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
});
```

C#

```
public async void Post([FromBody] string mydata){
   //code
}
```

Comment: ok its done , then how can i convert the base64 data to bytes ,  byte[] toBytes1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(b64);  .. this line getting wrong bytes

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733845/c-sharp-convert-a-base64-byte

Comment: getting null value in web api controller , here mydata is null, how can i send my data from ajaxcall , i used  data: JSON.stringify({"mydata":base64Data}) ..  `//POST: api/voice
        public async void Post([FromBody] string mydata)
        {  // code }`

Comment: @RamseenRamsi, do you add `[HttpPost]` verb for your method ?

Comment: yes i added now but still its returns null value , but when i add like this my method `string b64 = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;` i get data which i send from ajax  but not much as accurate , it seems to be corrupted.

Comment: your using mvc controller action method but mine is webapi controller `//POST: api/voice
        [HttpPost]
        public async void Post([FromBody] string mydata)
       {
            try
            {
                 string b64 = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
               
               
                var client = new HttpClient();`  may be thats why ?  its not able to get the data in paramaeter (string mydata) ??

Comment: so it wont work with webapi right ? is there any other way of code method where i can execute my scenario ?

Comment: Now ajax call must send the correct value to web api controller.

Comment: that part is done , ajax send base64 data correctly , but its not get receives by the webapi controller method . its hitting the method instance perfectly  .

Comment: i have done like this , `var dataJSON = base64data;` and in ajax data `$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '',
            data: JSON.stringify(dataJSON),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json'
        });`  its working fine for me ... thank you for your help :)